# Write a function to manipulate and then write a dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops

I would like to read in multiple .csv files (dataframes) from a folder and apply a function that I create to all the files. And finally this function will write the new .csv files.

I want the function to do the following 3 things

```
df$Class <- gsub("null", "OTHER", df$Class)

df$Class <- gsub(': ', ',', df$Class)

df <- df %>% select(c(Image, everything(.), -Name))
```

I don't really know how to put these thing into a function, but I've tried
`

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

tidy_up_fxn <- function(file_names) {
  df <- do.call(bind_rows,lapply(file_names,data.table::fread))
  df$Class <- gsub("null", "OTHER", df$Class)
  df$Class <- gsub(': ', ',', df$Class)
  df <- df %>% select(c(Image, everything(.), -Name))
  
  out <- function(df)
  fwrite(out, file = file_names, sep = ",")
  }

tidy_up_fxn(file_names)
```

`
When I run it, R gets busy for a few seconds and then nothing happens. Please, help correct my function!

Comment: I think the problem is this line:
out <- function(df)
This is defining another function within the function. Are you trying to return the data frame (as an object) or write the data frame to a file?

Comment: I agree with nd37255. Additionally ... (1) `bind_rows(.)` accepts a list, you don't need `do.call`, you can do `bind_rows(lapply(..))`. (2) If you're already using `data.table::fread`, you can use `rbindlist` (might want `use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE`). (3) For real memory-efficiency (if your data is large-ish), you can reduce the read/transform to `setcolorder(rbindlist(lapply(..))[, Class := gsub(": ", ",", gsub("null", "Other", Class))][, Name := NULL], "Image")`. (4) Sticking with what you have, `everything` doesn't need the `.`, you can use `everything()` (since it's inside `select(..)`.

Comment: (5) if `file_names` is a vector of 1 ***or more*** files, know that `fwrite` should complain: the `file=` must be length 1. Not only is the syntax broken, I think you're also confusing the potential of this function: if it reads in two (or more) files _and then combines into a single `data.frame`, then why are you trying to save that one frame back to multiple filenames? Are you intending to overwrite the original files? I argue that fixing files means one should save to new files.

Comment: Thank you all! To clarify, I am trying to make the changes and then write the data as new dataframes (not overwriting).

Comment: "new dataframes" (objects in an R working environment) or "new files"?

Answer (score 0):

The following works the way I intended to

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

tidy_up_fxn <- function(file_names) {
  df <- bind_rows(lapply(file_names,data.table::fread))
  df$Class <- gsub("null", "OTHER", df$Class)
  df$Class <- gsub(': ', ',', df$Class)
  df <- df %>% select(c(Image, everything(.), -Name))
  
 
    fwrite(df, file = "new.csv", sep = ",")
}

tidy_up_fxn(file_names)
```

Thank you all!!

Comment: I think it should be `function(file_names)` instead of `function(x)` ... or `lapply(x, ..)` instead of `lapply(file_names, ..)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the change!